# Beautiful Soup Out of Index

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a simple program prints the stock price when I input a google finance address.

The current code I am using is as follows.

```
import requests
import bs4
def pricechecker(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')
    print (soup.select('span.unchanged')[0].text)
```

When I run the code I have been using http://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3AAAPL&ei=4UJrVomFNZGje7y-pJAP as a parameter. Upon running the code it states that the list index is out of range. I used firebug to get the CSS for the soup.select portion of my code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to programming and would like to correct my mistakes.

Best,

Hunter

Comment: Hint: do `print(soup.select('span.unchanged'))` to see the result

Comment: I gave that a try before I tried to index into it and it just returns and empty list. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: So what are you expecting when you index an empty list?

Comment: I want it to print the price of the stock

Comment: Do you have to scrape it from the website? There are better ways of getting stock prices. My guess is that there is a script that runs to populate the field you're trying to scrape. So since you're requesting the html outside the browser, there is no way for javascript to fill that in.

Comment: @HunterSneed did that work for you? Hook a brother up and accept the answer if yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick check shows that the raw html you get from this request will not have "unchanged" anywhere in it: try running

```
curl ﻿http://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3AAAPL&ei=4UJrVomFNZGje7y-pJAP | grep "unchanged"
```

There will be no results.

Or if you don't like the command line, you can try this in python:

```
r = requests.get(url)
print("unchanged" in r.text)  # will be False
```

There will be no matches.This is because "unchanged" values only show up once the page's javascript loads data into `<span class="unchanged"></span>` tags that are also generated in the javascript.

There is a [googlefinance Python library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googlefinance) that you can use to get this data. Of course first install: `pip install googlefinance`. Then

```
from googlefinance import getQuotes
aapl = getQuotes('AAPL')
print(aapl)  # provides a bunch of info in a list including...
last_price = aapl[0]['LastTradePrice']
```

`last_price` is a string, so to convert to a float, `float(aapl[0]['LastTradePrice'])`.